# OpenCL AMD Incompatible GPU

Tags: gpu, opencl

I recently installed an AMD graphics card in my machine (Radeon RX570 to be exact), which should be OpenCL 2.0 compatible according to AMD, but when I try to set my Cycles render device to OpenCL, I get the "no compatible GPUs found for path tracing" error. This is my first time using an AMD graphics card- are any additional drivers are required for OpenCL to work in Blender?

I am running Linux Mint 19.3. inxi -G returns:

````
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X] 
  driver: amdgpu v: 5.4.7.20.10 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: amdgpu,ati 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 
  resolution: 1280x1024~60Hz, 1024x768~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Radeon RX 570 Series 
  v: 4.6.13594 Core Profile Context 20.10 ```
````

Answer (score 1):

GPU rendering with OpenCL requires the proprietary AMD drivers on Linux. This is documented in [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/gpu/linux/amd.html#drivers):

> AMD drivers are open source, *except for the OpenCL support which is available as part of Pro drivers*. Installing packages through your Linux distribution is usually best. AMD also provides graphics drivers for download on their website if you need the latest version.
>
> [AMD Drivers and Support Website](https://www.amd.com/en/support)

Comment: Thanks. So, once I download that driver, the command is ./amdgpu-isntall --pro, yes? Do I need to do anything else? I'm still getting the error... (still kind of new to Linux and Blender)

Answer (score 0):

#### CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST env var

In my case with AMD 530 mobile I got it detected only after reading source ([OpenCLInfo::get_usable_devices](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/f48d15a86189756ae7dd9b7ba45fb3af24e0846b/intern/cycles/device/opencl/opencl_util.cpp#L906) -> [OpenCLInfo::device_supported](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/f48d15a86189756ae7dd9b7ba45fb3af24e0846b/intern/cycles/device/opencl/opencl_util.cpp#L761)) and finding `CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST` environment variable check:

```
$ CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=1 ./blender --debug-cycles --log-level '-1'
```

Now go to Edit > Preferences > System > Cycles Render Devices > OpenCL

```
opencl_util.cpp:945 Enumerating devices for platform Clover.
opencl_util.cpp:983 Adding new device AMD ICELAND (DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-37-generic, LLVM 9.0.1).
```

Without this variable it was

```
opencl_util.cpp:995 Ignoring device AMD ICELAND ..., not officially supported yet.
```

#### Open question

What is `VLOG(3)` in `OpenCLInfo::device_supported` and how do I send it to stderr/stdout?

#### No proprietory drivers

Also , I didn't install proprietary drivers, just `sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd`

#### OpenCL C 1.1 static error

And it doesn't work when I try to actually [render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html) anything with it. I guess the relevant line from the log is

```
error: OpenCL C version 1.1 does not support the 'static' storage class specifier
```

YMMV.